# What is the workflow of Eclipse Project Clean

Tags: java, eclipse, project

Can anyone tell step-by-step what happens when I run Eclipse *Project --> Clean*?
Like in this way -

```
1. All source codes are compiled
2. Checkstyle verification (as I have the plugin)
...
```

Also, can I skip some of the tasks to save time?

Comment: 0. clean, i.e. delete all generated files / data - 1. is already optional and does what building always does, i.e. (re)generate all missing or outdated files / data.

Comment: @burna I think my question is slightly different ;)

Comment: @Saik0 How so? On first glance I would say its the same. You are requesting a tad more details, but you don't make that pretty clear in your question. I recommend adding the information that you have read the linked question and how this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it will be useful to understand Eclipse Builder framework. Simplified each project has a list of builders roughly one for each task to perform on the source code. In your case you will have a Java Builder and a Checkstyle Builder. Each builders can perform different actions dependent on the type of build you are executing, e.g. a full build, an incremental build, or cleaning.

What happens when you click Project -> Clean is this

1. For every project, Eclipse tell each builder in turn to perform their clean action

If you have auto build enabled it continues to build.

1. First it calculates the dependencies between projects and creates an ordering of projects that ensures dependencies are build before the projects that depend on them.
2. Following that ordering the builders of each project is told to perform a full build.

The ordering of builders within a projects is definded in a projects meta-data (the `.project`file). You can view the ordering by right clicking on a project and go to `Properties -> Builders`

If you want to know what happens in more details take a look at these pages:

- What Exactly is a Builder: [Eclipse - What is exactly a Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208851/eclipse-what-is-exactly-a-builder)
- Project Builders and Natures: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html

Comment: Remember to accept :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer